# How did this user bypass the question rate limit?

Tags: support, rate-limiting

This [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6226210/user6226210) was able to ask two [dupli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36757885/data-structure-and-cound)-[cate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36757817/data-structure-and-count) questions (now deleted, there was a triplicate 2 hours earlier) within 10 minutes of each other.

The limit [seems to be](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164900)

> Users < 125 rep, 20 minutes (90 minutes on Stack Overflow)

How did they bypass this limit?

Comment: The titles were almost identical. The change in the very last letter allowed that by. As for your question: I assume that they found another loophole. Maybe the throttle is imposed when you click the "ask q" button, so they could have had 2 pages open at once.

Comment: Funny how one of them starts with "up vote 0 down vote favorite", showing they clearly copy/pasted from their own question and accidentally grabbed the voting arrows too.

Comment: User could have had more rep at the time and lost it (due to deleted posts, or deleted users if he was committing voting fraud).  He could also have posted them under different accounts and since had those accounts merged.

Comment: Well, both questions have gone now...

Comment: FIY, [this was the 3rd question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36756279/read-data-and-add-row). Deleted now as well. But they did re-ask [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36752646/1743880) which has the same content as the previous ones. This one is live, so that makes it 4.

Comment: Being sub 10k really sucks on meta :( All the interesting stuff is deleted by the time I get to see it

Comment: @AlexanderDerck There's nothing interesting here, except the dates. The questions themselves are garbage. Maybe in other posts...

Comment: @Pillar Everything is interesting if you hear about it but can't see it. Curiosity is a strange thing

Comment: @Tunaki Actually, the question that's still open was the first one they asked. I have no idea what prompted them to ask it 3 more times after receiving 3 answers.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: Momentary insanity, probably